# I'm not able to use webpack-dev-server Unexpected token export at new Script (vm.js:74:7)

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I get the following error when I run 'npm run start' or run 'node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server' from the command line:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
at Module.m._compile (/sites/thr-int/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:403:23)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/sites/thr-int/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:406:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

I'm using Webpack 4.8.3 with the following configuration files:
webpack.config.ts:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
console.log("dev mode:>>> ", devMode);
const config: webpack.Configuration = 
{
    mode: 'production',
    entry:[ './src/index.ts', './src/styles/style.scss' ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
output: 
{
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
module: 
{
    rules: 
    [
        {
            test: /\.css$/, 
            use: 
            [
                'style-loader',
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoader : 1 } }
                ,'postcss-loader'
            ] 
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {

            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            use: 
            [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: 
                    {
                        includePaths: ["./src/styles/style.scss"],
                        sourceMap: true,
                        importLoader: 2
                    }
                },
                "postcss-loader",
                "sass-loader"
            ]

        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: ['file-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            use: ['file-loader']
        }
    ],  
},
resolve: 
{
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
},
  plugins: 
  [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin (
        {
            filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])

        ,new HtmlWebpackPlugin (
        {
            title: 'Thought Render'
        })

  ],
  };
 export default config;
```

tsconfig-for-webpack-config.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs" ,

  "target": "es5"
    }
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
      {
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "module": "es2015",
  "target": "es6",
  "jsx": "preserve",
  "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

inside of my package.json file:

```
      {
    "name": "thr-int",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "interactive part of thought render site",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
      "build": "TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig-for-webpack-config.json\" webpack"
    },
    "author": "deriv diggs",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/lodash": "^4.14.109",
      "@types/node": "^10.1.2",
      "@types/webpack": "^4.4.0",
      "autoprefixer": "^8.5.2",
      "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
      "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
      "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
      "jquery": "^3.3.1",
      "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
      "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
      "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
      "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
      "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
      "postcss-preset-env": "^5.1.0",
      "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
      "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
      "sugarss": "^1.0.1",
      "ts-loader": "^4.3.0",
      "ts-node": "^6.0.3",
      "tsconfig-paths": "^3.3.2",
      "typescript": "^2.8.3",
      "webpack": "^4.8.3",
      "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
      "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
      "@types/node-sass": "^3.10.32",
      "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4",
      "lodash": "^4.17.10",
      "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
      "save-dev": "^2.0.0"
    }
  }
```

index.ts

```
        import * as $ from "jquery";
    (<any>window).jQuery = $

    import * as _ from "lodash";

    import "bootstrap";

    import { Print } from "./Print"

    const Logo = require('./images/logo_thr_circle.png');

    let printMe:Print = new Print();

    /**
     * Fires when everything is loaded and ready to GO!
     */
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event):void 
    { 
        document.body.appendChild(component());

        document.body.appendChild(componentO());



    });

    function component() 
    {
        let element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack w/typscript bout time but no sass :('], ' ');

        element.classList.add('hello');

        let myLogo = new Image();
        myLogo.src = Logo;
        element.appendChild(myLogo);

        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = 'Click for console';
        btn.onclick =  printMe.printer;

        element.appendChild(btn);

        return element;
    }

    function componentO() 
    {
        let elementO = document.createElement('div');
        elementO.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'SASS'], ' ');

        elementO.classList.add('helloWorld');
        return elementO;
    }
```

When I run 'npm run build' everything works as expected. I've been googling for a couple of days now . Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Set `TS_NODE_PROJECT` value in your `start` script as well.

```
"start": "TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig-for-webpack-config.json\" webpack-dev-server --open"
```